# How do I return collection from another model?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I can only return data for Orders table eg.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "external_id": 1,
      "refer_order_id": 1364116832365,
...
    },
```

I need to also return data related to that table. In Artisan Tinker it is done like this...

```
$order = App\Order::first();
$order->carts;
```

This will supply the Carts related to the Order table.

Resource/Order.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Order extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

api.php

```
        Route::get('/orders/bulkindex/', function () {
            return new OrderCollection(Order::all());
        });
```

Resources\Cart.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Cart extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

I'd like to return the data like so... WITH the carts info related to that data.

```
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection,
            'carts' => CartResource::collection($this->carts),
        ];
```

This will return this error:

> Exception Property [carts] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load the model relationship but you can't access it after it has been collected

It must be returned with the query to collect

```php
Route::get('/orders/bulkindex/', function () {
    return new OrderCollection(Order::with(['carts', 'another'])->get());
});
```

This will return the relationship appended to the data, not sure how you can serialize it independently tho

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks that works, Any idea if I wanted to include another table as well?

Comment: Just add it to an array passed to `with`

Answer (score 0):

Use eager load:

```
Order::with('carts')->get();
```

With multiple table

```
Order::with(['table1', 'table2'])->get();
```